# Python sub module import

Tags: python, import, directory-structure

Lets say i have an app with a GUI.

the folder structure is:

```
\project
   run.py
   gui.py
   \tracker
      tracker.py
      trackerdialog.py
      trackerDB.py
```

run.py is the main app entry point. it imports a bunch of packages including "import tracker.tracker"

while I'm working on tracker.py, tracker.py reads:
`import trackerDialog, trackerDB`

when I run tracker.py, everything works but when I import tracker from run.py. run.py errors with "no module named trackerDialog"

What is the proper way to import this submodule so i can test it isolated as tracker.py but also still have run.py be able to import it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base it from the working directory of the main program

```py
from tracker import trackerdialog, trackerDB
```

You may also need to write a file named literally `__init__.py` (it does not need any content) to mark the directory `./tracker` as containing Python libs (more here: [What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for) )

---

To use the file as *both* a library in a directory and *also* directly run it, consider either

- creating a dedicated runner in the root directory
- try/excepting `ImportError`

  ```py
  try:
      from tracker import trackerdialog, trackerDB
  except:
      import trackerDialog, trackerDB
  ```

Comment: with that in tracker.py, it works from run.py but errors when running from tracker.py

Comment: Ah - if you wish to use it _both_ as a library in a directory and directly run it, consider a separate runner in the root directory or simply try/excepting `ImportError` amongst the imports and importing it with the relative import as you were in the except block

Comment: sounds good, wasnt sure what the proper way to do something like this was, try/excepting the import seems like a good solution. ill accept it if you write up a new answer or add it to the one above